# OS X Mountain Lion Java version

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, java

I would like to use java and javac on Mac OS X 10.8.2, but in the terminal when I ask for version with this command: `java -version` or `javac -version` it returns the following versions:

```
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
```

and

```
javac 1.6.0_37
```

When I go to the settings app and tap on the Java icon in the `Other` section, it opens the Java Control Panel and there the jre version is `1.7.0_10`

Which is used? And how can I update the java in terminal, not to use the 1.6.0 version?
Does anybody experienced this problem?

Comment: What's on your path? `echo $PATH | grep java`

Comment: my $PATH doesn't contain Java, it was containing the 1.6 version, but I removed to solve this issue, but it didn't solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Java Preference App, you may find several JDKs, you can drag JDK7 to the top of the list, then re-open the shell, and invoke java -version. It will change to the JDK7.

Comment: There was only 1 choice, but I've downloaded from the oracle's site, the latest sdk and it appears now also in terminal.